# Как исправить ошибку в теле метода?

Tags: java, парсер

Известно что где-то в теле метода возвращающего сумму двух чисел есть ошибка и её нужно исправить. Изменения вносить можно только в тело метода.

```
public class Praktikum2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String firstNumber = "123.45";
        String secondNumber = "234.56";
        System.out.println(addNumbers(firstNumber, secondNumber));

    }

    private static Float addNumbers(String firstNumber, String secondNumber) {
        return Float.parseFloat(firstNumber + secondNumber);
    }
}
```

В каком направлении двигаться в поиске решения?

Comment: ну запусти и посмотри что там получается

Comment: @Эникейщик Вот такое:  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: multiple points
 at java.base/jdk.internal.math.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:1914)
 at java.base/jdk.internal.math.FloatingDecimal.parseFloat(FloatingDecimal.java:122)
 at java.base/java.lang.Float.parseFloat(Float.java:476)
 at com.MFP.Praktikum2.addNumbers(Praktikum2.java:13)
 at com.MFP.Praktikum2.main(Praktikum2.java:8)

Process finished with exit code 1

Я не понимаю что это значит.

Comment: здесь написано, какая ошибка (NumberFormatException) и на какой строчке (13)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`+` для строк - это конкатенация.

`Float.parseFloat` - "превращает" строку в число с плавающей точкой.

Получается надо применить этот метод к **каждому из параметров** и уже только потом складывать эти данные между собой и возвращать результат

Comment: Дай бог тебе здоровья! Спасибо что направил в нужное русло! Я получил нужный ответ. Вот что я добавил : 
`private static Float addNumbers(String firstNumber, String secondNumber) {
        Float v = Float.parseFloat(firstNumber);
        Float x = Float.parseFloat(secondNumber);
        return x + v;`

Comment: Хорошо.  в целом это можно сократить до `return Float.parseFloat(firstNumber) + Float.parseFloat(secondNumber);`